# How to deal with the server sending two different cookies for consecutive requests?

Tags: node.js, express, http, session, cookies

When I have two synchronous consecutive fetch request made on the same page, the server makes two different sessions for that client. This is because the second request is sent to the server *before* the the first response sends back the Set-Cookie header to the client.

The console shows that both request didn't send a cookie. Therefore, both responses created a new session.

```
-----------'/first' request------------
'req.headers.cookie: undefined
'req.sessionID: uZCc-2EtuOIdqD5xfcBCBLQjZbRmy29k
'/first' Set-Cookie header: connect.sid=s%3AuZCc-2EtuOIdqD...

-----------'/second' request------------
'req.headers.cookie: undefined
'req.sessionID: Gzr5CPYvE5deGA-Ul7EwOzHbaWFtpXR3
'/second' Set-Cookie header: connect.sid=s%3AGzr5CPYvE5deGA...
```

You can further see this  problem is caused by the second request firing too soon when you uncomment `// await addNSecondsDelay(5);` (remember clear your cookies to replicate) to create a 5 second delay. This will create only one session.

I don't want an extra unused session created every time a new client visits a page with multiple requests. I can think of a few ways to fix this- like calling fetch asynchronously- but that seems like it wouldn't fit more complex situations perhaps where the html page is created dynamically and you can't chain together the fetch calls for each dynamically generated component. It also seems that would slow the page from loading too much.

Is there a proper way to make sure two sessions aren't created?

### Backend server

```js
// other-server.js
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const sess = {
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  secret: 'very secret 12345',
  cookie: {
    sameSite: true,
    secure: false,
  },
};

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
app.use(session(sess));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`\n-----------'${req.path}' request------------`);

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Accept, Content-Type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:5001');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH'
  );
  res.on('close', function () {
    console.log(
      `'${req.path}' Set-Cookie header: ${res.getHeaders()['set-cookie'][0].slice(0, 30)}...`
    );
  });
  req.session.a = 'hi';
  console.log(`'req.headers.cookie: ${req.headers.cookie}`);
  console.log(`'req.sessionID: ${req.sessionID}`);
  next();
});
app.post('/first', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "1st fetch's response" });
});
app.post('/second', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "2nd fetch's response" });
});

app.listen(4001, () => {
  console.log('start');
});
```

### Frontend server

```js
// server.js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.listen(5001);
```

### index.html

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      const addNSecondsDelay = (n) => {
        console.log('5 second delay ...');
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
          }, n * 1000);
        });
      };

      const asyncFunctionCall = async () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:4001/first', {
          method: 'POST',
          credentials: 'include',
        })
          .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((json) => {
            console.log('Received:  ' + JSON.stringify(json));
          });
        // await addNSecondsDelay(5);
        fetch('http://localhost:4001/second', {
          method: 'POST',
          credentials: 'include',
        })
          .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((json) => {
            console.log('Received:  ' + JSON.stringify(json));
          });
      };

      asyncFunctionCall();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you run the API on the same server as the web page is loaded from?  If so, then the very act of loading the web page into the browser would have already set the session cookie in the browser before any of your Javascript runs.

Comment: @jfriend00 for my specific use case I would prefer to keep them separate but this is good to know

Comment: I actually realized I did not need two different servers so I took this suggestion. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to run the API on the same server as the web page is loaded from? If so, then the very act of loading the web page into the browser would have already set the session cookie in the browser before any of your Javascript in the web page runs.

Answer (score 1):

These are your options:

1. Send 1 request before you do anything else, so you get exactly one cookie.
2. Make it so that having 2 cookies doesn't matter.

The last `Set-Cookie` header you receive 'wins', and there's no good way to know that these 2 requests are really from the same client (that's what a cookie is for), so you can't *directly* fix this easily.

The only other option I can think of is by letting the client generate some unique id itself and send that along with both requests, but I suspect that that's a can of worms as well in terms of security.